# Getting rsyslog to fwd to Splunk from Ubuntu .20.04

Tags: logs, syslog, rsyslog, haproxy

So I've got an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server setup with Haproxy and I'm trying to fwd log info to Splunk Cloud.

I have the Haproxy.cfg with a Global entry:

```
log 127.0.0.1 local4
```

And I've got an entry in /etc/rsyslog.conf for the remote server:

```
*.* @@10.1.1.1:1603
```

(The @@ is for TCP and yeah I'm using a non-standard port that was assigned to me for this by InfoSec)

The latest versions of Haproxy create it's own rsyslog config file /etc/rsyslog.d/hapyoxy.log with:

```
# Create an additional socket in haproxy's chroot in order to allow logging via
# /dev/log to chroot'ed HAProxy processes $AddUnixListenSocket /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log

# Send HAProxy messages to a dedicated logfile :programname, startswith, "haproxy" {   /var/log/haproxy.log   stop }
```

And finally I've added a line to /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf:

`local4.*               /var/log/haproxy.log`

So I *believe* I've got it all setup how it should be, so I run *logger "please work"* and I can see that line when I: tail /var/log/haproxy.log and tail /var/log/syslog but nothing on the remote end.
So then I try: *logger -n 10.1.1.1 -P 1603 "please really work"* but I don't see that line in any log file or the remote side.

So I REALLY hope I've just overlooked something simple. Any help would be dramatically appreciated.

##EDIT##

So using TCPdump and 'logger' I am able to send events to Splunk. But Haproxy to syslog still doesn't work.

Comment: Eh that's a typo from posting it here. Fixing it now.

Comment: Are you running HAProxy inside a chroot or docker environment?

Comment: HAproxy is, I guess the default config which I believe for a full OS is chroot'd.

Comment: You say there is a `/etc/rsyslog.d/hapyoxy.log` file, and you show its contents, but we see only 3 lines, all starting with `#`, so they are just comments. Do you have a newline before the words `$AddUnixListenSocket` and `:programname` or not? If not, then you should probably add the correct newlines so that this configuration is applied, and restart rsyslogd. If you then get local4 logs from haproxy, you need to move the `*.* @@10.1.1.1:1603` line into this file before the `stop` line.